# java.lang.NullPointerException: uri

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera, uri

Im trying to get the URI for the captured image from camera I why am i getting the exception as java.lang.NullPointerException: uri ,

here is my code.

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();


file = new File(URI(selectedImage)); 

public String URI(Uri contentUri)
 {
        Cursor cursor = null;

try
 {




String[] proj = {MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE};

     cursor=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri,proj,null,null,null);
      intcolumn_index=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your logcat?

Comment: UploadFragment: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri.

Comment: I'll edit my comment!! Can u post your complete error log?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.isFile()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   com.test.field.Fragments.UploadFragment$DicomFragment.onClick(UploadFragment.java:743)
                                                                                   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)

Comment: @Abilash Then you need to post the code where u r using isFile()?

Comment: You have to investigate for yourself (using debugging, breakpoints and Stetho or equivalent) why your data is nulled out here. It may be that your processing is destroying your uri at some point, or it's possible that your backend is sending you empty parameter.

Comment: @Raghavendra im checking file for                                                          if (outputFile.isFile())                                                                                   {                        new DICOM().execute();
                            getDialog().dismiss();
                        }

Comment: your `contentUri` is null, and you try to call the method from it. That's why it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You have many problems in this code, even ignoring the fact that it is incomplete. I am going to assume, based on your words, that you are calling `startActivity()` for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and that the code in your question is from `onActivityResult()`.

First, the result from `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not provide you with a `Uri` to anything. If you used `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, then your image is supposed to be wherever you requested it to be, based on the value you put into `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Otherwise, you get back a `Bitmap`, representing a thumbnail-sized image, from `data.getExtra("data")`.

Second, `file = new File(URI(selectedImage));` is completely meaningless, even if `selectedImage` was not `null`. AFAIK, that line will not even compile. Even if it did, a `Uri` is not a `File.`

Third, `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not a valid column to retrieve from the `MediaStore`.

Fourth, you are assuming that the `MediaStore` knows something about the picture that the camera app took. There is no requirement that the camera app tell the `MediaStore` about this picture.

FWIW, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrates taking a photo using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, then using a `Uri` to that image with `ACTION_VIEW` to go view the image.